# Print the type name of object held by variable

Tags: java

In Java, is it possible to print the type of value held by variable?

```
public static void printVariableType(Object theVariable){
    //for example, if passed argument is "abc", print "String" to the console.
}
```

One approach to this problem would be to use an if-statement for each variable type, but that would seem redundant, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this:

```
if(theVariable instanceof String){
    System.out.println("String");
}
if(theVariable instanceof Integer){
    System.out.println("Integer");
}
// this seems redundant and verbose. Is there a more efficient solution (e. g., using reflection?).
```

Comment: This question has a deceptively similar title to this one, but appears to be mostly irrelevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614066/how-can-i-print-out-the-type-size-and-range-of-a-java-data-type-esp-those-wti

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I am assuming that in case of `Animal myPet = new Cat();` you want to get `Cat` not `Animal` nor `myPet`.

To get only name without package part use

```
String name = theVariable.getClass().getSimpleName(); //to get Cat
```

otherwise

```
String name = theVariable.getClass().getName(); //to get full.package.name.of.Cat
```

Answer (score 17):

```
System.out.println(theVariable.getClass());
```

Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `".getClass()"` method.

```
System.out.println(variable.getClass());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
variable.getClass().getName();
```

[Object#getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29)

> Returns the runtime class of this Object. The returned Class object is
>   the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the
>   represented class.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void printVariableType(Object theVariable){
    System.out.println(theVariable.getClass())
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can read in the class, and then get it's name.

```
Class objClass = obj.getClass();  
System.out.println("Type: " + objClass.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printVariableType(Object theVariable){
    System.out.println(theVariable);        
    System.out.println(theVariable.getClass()); 
    System.out.println(theVariable.getClass().getName());}



   ex- printVariableType("Stackoverflow");
    o/p: class java.lang.String // var.getClass()
         java.lang.String       // var.getClass().getName()
```