# Finding the type of variable, knowing it's a primitive datatype

Tags: java

I read this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770469/print-the-type-of-a-java-variable) that allows us to tell us what data type the object entails.
Is there a way to do that with primitive data types? Does that mean I would have to autbox the variable then apply some method to it? For instance:

```java
float d1 = 10;
float d2 = 10.1f;
double d3 = d1 + d2;
```

Is there a way for me to print `d3`'s data type?

TIA

Comment: Don't you know it? `System.out.println("double")`?

Comment: I probably should clarify my question. I know it's a double. But I was thinking if there was something for Java to tell me that it's a double

Comment: Why would that be any useful? `getClass` shown in your linked question is useful because the programmer doesn't know the type of object that is passed to `printVariableType`. But here you know 100% that `d3` is `double`... You can get the `Class` of `double` using `double.class`, but that's it.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a helper method in order to perform boxing, and use `getClass()`

```
public static <T> Class<?> typeOf(final T value) { 
  return value.getClass(); 
}
```

```
jshell> double x = 10.0;
x ==> 10.0
jshell> float y = 10.0f;
y ==> 10.0
jshell> typeOf(y)
$4 ==> class java.lang.Float
jshell> typeOf(x)
$5 ==> class java.lang.Double
```